# Create overlapping subsets python

Tags: python, chunks

My question is this:

If for example we have a list of numbers in order from 1 to 1200 like:
1,2,3,4,5,...,1200
How can we extract for a specific size (lets say 400) the following chunks in python:
1-400, 200-600,  400-800, 600-1000, 800-1200

what i made so far is this:

```
a = [i for i in range(1200)]
swift_number = 400
num1 = 0
num2 = num1 + swift_number
while (len(a) - num1) > swift_number:
    print "getting numbers from %s to %s", num1, num2
    num1 = num2 - swift_number / 2
    num2 = num1 + swift_number
```

Comment: You can use slicing notation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation. Like a[0:400] if I get understand you.

Comment: As a sidenote: `[i for i in range(1200)]` → `list(range(1200))`

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of slice notation, it is possible to simplify a lot:

```
a = list(range(1200))
swift_number = 400          # how many items per chunk
step = int(swift_number/2)  # how many items we shift for each chunk

chunks = [
    a[base:base+swift_number]
    for base in range(0, len(a), step)
]
```

That makes `chunks` be a list of lists. First list has items [0..399], second list has items [200..599], third list has items [400..799] and so on.

This can be put on a single line:

```
chunks = [a[base:base+swift_number] for base in range(0, len(a), step)]
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to address sub-lists, use *ranged indices*:

```
x=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
y=x[2:4] ## evaluates to [30, 40, 50]
```

so your code would look like:

```
a=list(range(1, 1200+1))
width=400
for slice in range(2*len(a)/width - 1):
   index=slice*width/2
   print("%s" % (a[index:index+width]))
```

Comment: I think that your extension looses the first 0 - 400. Or not ? In order to show the first 0 -400 the print statement must come first

Comment: @GiorgosPerakis ah yes, thanks; i was more interested in showing how to use ranges...fixed

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using `itertools.groupby`

```
import itertools

[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(xrange(1, 1201), lambda x: not(x % 400))]
```